# How to prevent double click on the submit form? Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

Whenever i want to upload an image and click on the submit button twice, the image is showing twice, and when i click on the submit button 3 times it shows three times also. Any help with just javascript would be appreciated guys. Below is my code:

```
const createForm = document.querySelector('#create-form');
createForm.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
    e.preventDefault();


    const ref = firebase.storage().ref();

    const images = createForm['upload-file'].files;
    const list = []


    for await(img of images){
        if (img !== 'length'){
        const name = new Date() + '-' + img.name
        const metadat = { contentType: img.type }
        const task = await ref.child(name).put(img, metadat)
            .then(snapshot => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
            list.push(task)}
    }


    // adding to the Database
    await db.collection('properties').add({
        title: createForm['create-title'].value,
        city: createForm['add-city'].value,
        type: createForm['type-rent-sale'].value,
        rooms: createForm['add-rooms'].value,
        price: createForm['add-price'].value,
        image: list
    }).then(() => {
        //reset form
        createForm.reset();
    }).then( () => {
        //close modal
        const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-create');
        M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
})
```

here is my HTML

```
<form id="create-form">

          <div class = "file-field input-field">
            <div class = "btn indigo">
               <span>Browse</span>
               <input type = "file" multiple id="upload-file" />
            </div>

            <div class = "file-path-wrapper">
               <input class = "file-path validate" type = "text"
                  placeholder = "Upload multiple files" />
            </div>
         </div>
          <button class="btn indigo z-depth-0">Create Post</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with your HTML markup as well please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
var clicker = 0; // init click check
const createForm = document.querySelector('#create-form');
createForm.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
e.preventDefault();
++clicker; // increase on every click
if (clicker == 1) { // if it first time

createForm.setAttribute('disabled', 'true'); // prevent another clicks.

const ref = firebase.storage().ref();

const images = createForm['upload-file'].files;
const list = []


for await(img of images){
    if (img !== 'length'){
    const name = new Date() + '-' + img.name
    const metadat = { contentType: img.type }
    const task = await ref.child(name).put(img, metadat)
        .then(snapshot => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
        list.push(task)}
}


// adding to the Database
await db.collection('properties').add({
    title: createForm['create-title'].value,
    city: createForm['add-city'].value,
    type: createForm['type-rent-sale'].value,
    rooms: createForm['add-rooms'].value,
    price: createForm['add-price'].value,
    image: list
}).then(() => {
    //reset form
    createForm.reset();
    createForm.removeAttribute('disabled'); // make it clickable again
    clicker = 0;
}).then( () => {
    //close modal
    const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-create');
    M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
})
}
else {return} // fallback
})
```

---

You can use variable to disable the button after the click:

```
var clicker = 0;
const createForm = document.querySelector('#create-form');
createForm.addEventListener('submit', async e => {  
  e.preventDefault();
  ++clicker;
  if (clicker == 1) { this.setAttribute('disabled', 'true'); 
  // and execute rest of code 
  }
  else {return} // fallback since the button is already disabled
```

And then after everything work as expected remove the disable attribute from the button.

Edit for clarification: After the code execute you can set clicker to 0 and remove the disabled attribute via `removeAttribute`

Comment: That's an incomplete solution without also having `--clicker` when the image either successfully loads or fails to load.

Comment: @kshetline Thank you for replay. a. This is full solution given the fact OP's code works. b. After code execute OP need to either remove attribute or set clicker to 0. I will edit it more if that not clear.

Comment: Can you write it inside my code since it did not work. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event handler, add the attribute 'disabled' to the button so it wont be "clickable" until you finish handling the files.

Comment: Can you please write it inside my code and paste it here again? since its not working

Comment: I can't do that as you didn't provided any html.

Comment: i have added the html, you can check it again, thanks